# Cannot compile non-english languages with babel

Tags: babel, compilation-error

I have the full texlive 2021 that I installed from Tug using install-tl --not the distro version.

I am using both TeXstudio and TexWorks and the command line; all have the same issue for pdf or lualatex:

```
Package fontenc Error: Encoding file `t2aenc.def' not found. \ProcessOptions*
Encoding scheme `T2A' unknown. \fontencoding\encodingdefault
Package babel Error: Unknown option `russian'. Either you misspelled itd. \ProcessOptions*
Encoding scheme `T2A' unknown. \begin{document}
Undefined control sequence. \foreignlanguiage
Package babel Error: You haven't defined the language russian yet. \begin{otherlanguage}{russian}
Encoding scheme `T2A' unknown. \end{document}
Encoding scheme `T2A' unknown. \end{document}
inputenc package ignored with utf8 based engines.
```

I looked in /usr/local/texlive and the files for babel are there.

I  messed with PATH too:

```
ghost@mirage:/usr/local/texlive/2021/bin$ export PATH
ghost@mirage:/usr/local/texlive/2021/bin$ INFOPATH=/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/doc/info:$INFOPATH
ghost@mirage:/usr/local/texlive/2021/bin$ export INFOPATH
ghost@mirage:/usr/local/texlive/2021/bin$ MANPATH=/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/doc/man:$MANPATH
ghost@mirage:/usr/local/texlive/2021/bin$ export MANPATH
```

Still the same problem. I appear to not be connecting anywhere.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english, russian]{babel}

\begin{document}

Beginning contract.
\foreignlanguiage{russian}{Система}
\begin{otherlanguage}{russian}
    Система-Система
\end{otherlanguage}
Bye
\end{document}
```

I would prefer not to use the distro version, it's from 2017. I ran install-tl on my last computer and never had issues, so I have no idea what this is now. Any suggestions on how to get a compilation?

Linux Mint 19.1
4.15.0-184-generic x86_64

Comment: The error message is clear: `\foreignlanguiage` doesn't exist. Probably `\foreignlanguage`?

Comment: You also seem to be getting an error message about T2A and the Russian babel files being missing. So, make sure those are installed. (Using `tlmgr` with a custom installation or the package manager if not. (For example, the `t2a.enc` file should be part of the `t2` package on `tlmgr`.)

Comment: The extra "i" is a typo that was fised, but the errors still remain concerning an inability to find the files.
The files are there and installed, they just cannot be seen.